# CSV merging and adding new row to each column in each file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, machine-learning, pycharm

I have bunch of files and file standard goes like

```
TestAP300
TestBP300
TestCP300
...
TestHP30
```

For Example:

```
Data A: 

"-0.9148","-1.7609","0.8441","-3.0872"
"-2.4155","-0.7446","0.7238","-1.5506"

Data B: 

"-0.2695","0.2271","0.7103","-4.7732"
"-0.5421","-0.6235","0.2131","-3.3143"

I would like to create file below :

"-0.9148","-1.7609","0.8441","-3.0872","A"
"-2.4155","-0.7446","0.7238","-1.5506","A"
"-0.2695","0.2271","0.7103","-4.7732","B"
"-0.5421","-0.6235","0.2131","-3.3143","B"
```

Each files has 10 columns and 4 rows. I would like to merge files in only one file and adding new row to each column.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you provide small reproducible example with two input data sets (3 columns, 3 rows each) and desired resulting data set?

Comment: Done it. Thank for tips :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input files:**

a.csv:

```
"-0.9148","-1.7609","0.8441","-3.0872"
"-2.4155","-0.7446","0.7238","-1.5506"
```

b.csv:

```
"-0.2695","0.2271","0.7103","-4.7732"
"-0.5421","-0.6235","0.2131","-3.3143"
```

**Solution:**

```
import os
import glob
import csv
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob(r'D:\temp\.data\43055344\*.csv')

pd.concat(
    [pd.read_csv(files[0], header=None).assign(f=os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(f)[0]))
     for f in files
    ],
    ignore_index=True
).to_csv(r'd:/temp/out.csv', header=None, index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

**Result:**

```
"-0.9148","-1.7609","0.8441","-3.0872","a"
"-2.4155","-0.7446","0.7238","-1.5506","a"
"-0.9148","-1.7609","0.8441","-3.0872","b"
"-2.4155","-0.7446","0.7238","-1.5506","b"
```

Comment: Thank you, it gave me an idea to do it.